# What happens when you assign a reference to a newly-created stack-allocated object?

Tags: c++, memory-management, reference, stack

In this code:

```
SomeClass& some_object = SomeClass();
```

What does some_object refer to? Is it valid? Or  undefined behavior at all?

Comment: Have you tried to compile it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Answer (score 2):

This is not valid according to the standard. However, some compilers (notably MSVC) will allow it as an extension.

You *are* allowed to assign a temporary to a reference-to-const, which will result in the lifetime of that temporary being extended to that of the reference:

```
{
    const SomeClass& some_object = SomeClass();
    // more code, some_object is valid
} //some_object is destructed here
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not valid, as in should not compile:

An rvalue cannot bind to a non-`const` lvalue reference.

However some compilers, e.g. MSVC, allow binding rvalues to non-`const` lvalue references as a compiler extension.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't compile at all.

Non-const references (`T&`) are not allowed to be bound to temporaries. You can bind temporaries to `const T&` or, since C++11, `T&&`, though:

```
const SomeClass& obj = SomeClass();
SomeClass&& obj = SomeClass();
```